# Issue with composer install "svn" is not recognized?

Tags: windows, svn

Hey so I am getting this error while using composer install in my project directory...

Anyone know what must be done? I downloaded svn from here http://www.sliksvn.com/en/support/

I am on a windows 8 machine.

This is the error:

```
[RuntimeException]
 Package could not be downloaded, 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or
 external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn.exe` must be in a location that is referenced by your `PATH` environment variable, or you need to configure composer (whatever that may be) to look for it in its installed location.